# Windows Phone 7 and native C++/CLI

Tags: windows-phone-7, arm, c++-cli, native, jit

Microsoft recently released tools and documentation for its new Phone 7 platform, which to the dismay of those who have a big C++ codebase (like me) doesn't support native development anymore. Although I've found speculation about this decision being reversed, I doubt it. So I was thinking how viable would be to make this codebase available to Phone 7 by adapting it to compile under C++/CLI. Of course the user interface parts couldn't be ported, but I'm not sure about the rest. Anyone had a similar experience? I'm not talking about code that does heavy low-level stuff - but there's a quite frequent use of templates and smart pointers.

Comment: What?!? No native c++?

Comment: Right, you have to use either Silverlight or XNA, and both are based on .net framework. 
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/03/16/microsoft_windows_phone_7_details/

Comment: According to this Ars Technica "op-ed", maybe there's some hope that MS will revert that decision. We'll see...
http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/03/unitasking-in-a-sandbox-windows-phone-7-series-philosophy.ars

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539876/is-it-possible-to-program-for-windows-phone-7-in-standard-c-only/4540330#4540330

Comment: It appears Microsoft is finally opening up the possibility of native C/C++ support in the near future: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1755203-native-sdk-to-support-c-development?tracking_code=ae5a8719dfd614f0d5769f79f44497c4

Comment: Windows Phone 8 & support for C/C++: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/3b1e975e-7687-4530-881c-356893f23eb9/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

c++/cli can theoretically be used with WPF/Silverlight using the trick of replacing the C# generated from the XAML with a macro definition that can be used inside the main class in a code behind file. I worked out this technique but haven't had the motivation to take it beyond theory - I'm quite happy mixing languages.

As far as using c++/cli in a pure safe mode for your logic code, this may still not be possible but I'd love to hear how someone goes trying it now. Whilst researching it for Silverlight back in 2008 I found this daunting [silverlight forum comment](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/5329/16357.aspx):

*I just gave Silverlight&C++ it a try by compiling the MSIL from my C++ project into a Silverlight-compatible DLL. The good news: it works, and you can call this code from a Silverlight project. The bad news: The C++ compiler apparently uses MSIL instructions that Silverlight disallows.*

*So, if you try this, even with the simplest of programs, you'll almost immediately get the exception **"Operation could destabilize the runtime."** To me, this makes it seem less likely that we'll see Silverlight for C++ soon, as the compiler will need to behave quite a bit differently.*

Answer (score 11):

You can generate verifiable managed code in C++/CLI using the /clr:safe option. The problem is that most of your normal c++ code will not compile with that option.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What kinds of constructs, is it viable to make workarounds via conditional compilation, etc.

Answer (score 9):

C# is currently the only **supported** language for WinPhone7.

I fully expect that MS will add support for VB and C++/CLI in the future too, but don't expect to open up the native-code kimono anytime soon.

Native code just has too many issues to overcome, specifically around security, reliability, etc. Managed code is FAR easier to statically verify and FAR easier to control while running.

If you're upset about porting C++ code to C#, just be glad MS didn't force you to have to move to Objective-C ;)

From our own experience, the proces of porting well-written C++ to C# actually takes a lot less effort than one might at first expect. Sure, there's a learning curve, but you have that with any port. We actually got so much benefit from porting our core app and data engines to C# that we re-tooled our entire team to code in C# and port our C# back to C++ where necessary rather than the other way around! So far, we've only ported two modules back to C++ and call our C# code from our native code via interop instead.

Again, remember, WinPhone is a brand new platform using best of breed, highly-productive, next-generation development tools and platforms. It is not your father's WinMo.

If support for C++ is something you find to be crucially important, then make sure MS know - (respectfully and professionally) state your position in the MSDN forums and at developer events near you.

#### Update1: 2012-12-17:

While native C++ still isn't officially supported for Windows Phone 7, Windows Phone 8 now supports native C++ code so you can more easily port your existing C++ codebase(s) to Windows Phone 8 (as well as Windows 8 and Windows desktop apps).

While there isn't 100% compatibility between the Windows8/Phone8 platforms and API's right now, I expect the two platforms to become increasingly integrated over the next couple of releases.

This is especially true now that one of the key barriers to closer cooperation between Windows and other groups at Microsoft recently left the company ;)

#### Update2: 4/15/2014:

As per the recent announcements at //BUILD/ 2014, you can now start building "universal" apps in C++ & XAML, C#/VB & XAML or JavaScript & HTML that will run on Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1 and Xbox One! For more details on building Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps, **[read this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx)**.

Comment: What do you mean with well-written C++ ? There's a lot of ways to do C++. And correctness depends on what you are using it for. So I guess, "well-written C++" is a bit subjective..." 

On the other side, Objective-C++ does fully support C++, and there seem to be a lot of devs relying on it for performance intensive ( or big-library based apps )

Comment: What I mean by "well written C++" is that the code is maintainable, follows sound engineering practices, doesn't leak, doesn't block threads, doesn't depend on machine-specific aspects like byte ordering or machine word length, etc.

Comment: Apple does not force you to use Objective-C, it's just their GUI-language. It's perfectly fine to use C++ for iOS development or even mix both languages with Objective-C++. But MS forces me to port all my code to a new, well but similar language, which is also an island (MS only). So I have still a lot of work for porting and testing, and maintaing two code-bases when changes are done. This is not nice by MS.

Comment: This argument is now moot. You can now write Windows Phone 8 apps in C++ or C#/.NET. Oh, and in case you've not seen it yet, Mono supports C# on iOS/OSX/Linux/Android/etc. so it's far from a Microsoft-only platform. What non-Apple platforms wholly support Objective-C?

Comment: You can write Objective-C on Linux and Windows.  The language is supported by GCC and a good chunk of the libraries you find on a Mac are implemented by GNUstep.

Comment: @asveikau: While you can compile Objective-C for non-iOS/OSX platforms, there's practically no support for Obejective-C outside of the Apple ecosystem & platforms.

Comment: As someone who has compiled and run objc on Linux I find your comments condescending.  It is not exactly mainstream but I wouldn't call it hard to work with either.  I think such dismissive comments (such as unsolicited objc bashing and saying native code has "too many issues") are not constructive.

Comment: The C++ support on WP8 is still limited. Only 2 scenarios are supported: DirectX applications and WinRT modules. There is no support for writing XAML apps with C++. Your comment about managed code being *"FAR easier to control while running"* is awkward: Managed code is never run - it is always compiled to native instructions. Whatever leaves the compiler is executed. In terms of execution, there is no difference to truly native code. And certainly no more control.

Comment: @linspectable - thanks for your comments. Yes, WinPhone8's C++ support isn't yet at parity with Windows8, but I am hoping we'll see this differential diminish in the coming months and years as Microsoft FINALLY has its core OS' teams in one group. However, the ability to now use existing (potentially large) C++ codebases from within a WinPhone app may better satisfy the OP's scenario.

Comment: @linspectable: To your second point regarding managed code being "FAR easier to control while running", because IL compilers (JIT & NGEN) emit code with several safety barriers to protect array-overruns, operation re-ordering (via volatile keyword), etc., combined with the CLR's various safety mechanisms result in managed code being inherently "safer" than pure native code that executes without any oversight.

Answer (score 3):

The whole development idea is built on Silverlight. I think you can add your managed dll written in C++ without any problem to this Silverlight project, but it could not use native code.

I am planning to install the tools on my machine tonight and will try this out.

Comment: OK, I was guessing about that. But how much work it would be to make a typical modern C++ codebase (templates, smart pointers) compile under C++/CLI? Notice that it's not my idea to lose the ability to keep compiling native (to those platforms that support it, like WM6 and iPhone), but be able to mantain only one set of sources.

Comment: I would say that is closer to a complete rewrite than to a simple port.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine if MS decides to leave the path and create something new, that is MS' decision. So let's face the facts. Silverlight is no success yet. MS lost significant share due to Apple, Android and RIM. Application developers simply have to evaluate the business case for their own applications and decide if they trust in a share gain of Windows 7 phone or not. For the company that I run, we decided not to support any more MS Windows phone 7, not because of this or the other technical reason, but just because that we don't believe in the return of our investment for the port.
We start supporting Apple, Symbian, Andoid and MeeGo in the future if we see a market success of this new platform. All support C/C++ and enable us to reuse our proven application cores. So why worry at all. Personal technology preferences should not be gating. If personal preferences worry, then I would kick MS out for their to me ugly looking UI.

Thomas

Comment: Of the platforms you chose to adopt, MeeGo and Symbian are likely to crumble before your very eyes.

At the end of the day, Managed C++ compiles down to IL which is packaged into assemblies and executed by the CLR. If you're careful, you may well be able to get your code to port pretty cleanly to Managed C++ and thus run unhindered on WP7. If it doesn't work, however, you're on your own.

Things to avoid include direct memory manipulation, pointer arithmetic, etc., but then you're avoiding such things anyhow, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is on the horizon [finally](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/100979/599764.aspx)!

> So a survey sent to windows phone developers about their future
>   development preferences and XNA isn't mentioned once in the Survey (A
>   survey sent to windows phone developers - did I mention that)
>
> They do however ask:
>
> How would you prefer to use C++ in your mobile apps/games?
>
> - Develop apps/games that are C++ from top to bottom (UI, business logic, and platform
>     APIs)
> - Use C++ for business logic and then write platform abstraction layer
> - Use C++ for business logic use 3rd party runtime engines
> - I don’t want to use C++