# Windows Phone 7 SDK C or C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-7, opengl-es

Is there any way to use C or C++ on Windows Phone 7? Also i need access to OpenGL from C/C++ and some kind of adapter to C from, for example, C#.

Comment: There are multiple platforms for this project. And core written in C. So decision will be not to support WP7 soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to program for Windows Phone 7 in standard C++ only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539876/is-it-possible-to-program-for-windows-phone-7-in-standard-c-only)

Comment: Also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749150/windows-phone-7-native-code-support

Comment: And related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455372/windows-phone-7-and-c-cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot. You have to use C# and XNA.

Long answer:

- There is no OpenGL API on WP7. You have to use XNA for 3D graphics.
- You cannot use C++, only managed (.Net) languages. I'm not an expert but I believe officially supported languages are C#, VB.net and F# at the moment. However, you may be able to use other languages as long as you manage to compile those into valid MSIL assembly.
- Support for non-managed, native languages such as C++ is not coming anytime soon AFAIK.

Comment: Everything would have to be managed. Meaning he would have to rewrite OpenGL as Managed Code... with the many limitations the Windows Phone platform have.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone 8, you finally can.