# Is Silverlight the only option for WP7 App development?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is silverlight the only option for developing WP7 applications? What about Java? Or is there anything else that WP7 supports?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539876/is-it-possible-to-program-for-windows-phone-7-in-standard-c-only

Comment: Microsoft and Java don't play nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have these options (as of now):

- C# (Silverlight / XNA)
- VB.NET (Silverlight)
- [F#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/20/f-windows-phone-7-silverlight-templates-now-on-visual-studio-gallery.aspx) (Silverlight)

Ultimately, any CLI-based language can be used to build WP7 applications as long as it allows building WP7-specific assemblies (given the restrictions). Unoficially, it is known that there are [native hooks](http://blog.walshie.me/2010/11/12/windows-phone-7-native-apps-the-missing-link/) and it is possible to use COM inside a WP7 app, but this is not yet a part of the public SDK and an application that implements a native layer that is not directly authorized by Microsoft will not even get through the approval process.

Comment: You can also code parts of your app in IronRuby if you want to - although there are some limitations to this (see http://www.iron7.com for some examples).

Comment: Additionally, you can code parts of your app UI in HTML with javascript - but this really doesn't seem to give a good user experience within Metro at present.

Comment: Pure example of a CLI-based language. As I said, theoretically it can be any language as long as it compiles to MSIL and abides WP7 assembly rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement applications and games for WP7 using Silverlight (C# or Visual Basic (though VB not fully supported yet)) or XNA (C#) only at this time.

Comment: VB.Net is fully supported (since Nov 2010) but requires a separate download http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e97ea70-e479-4c05-814f-639d71690e5d