# cross mobile platforms programming

Tags: android, c++, ios, windows-phone-7, cross-platform

I'm new to mobile dev and I'm interested in developing the application for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone 7. And I'd like write less code. For the present time I see that C++ may fit well.

What I know is that :
it's possible to use C++ with Objective-C even in one file together for iOS, and I can link my c++ libs.

it's possible to use C++ through NDK on Android.
So I can write most of my app in c++ (except some very specific platform dependent parts) and make calls to my app through some sort of exposed Facade, right?

What can be done with windows phone 7? I know that it's .Net based. And in .NET it's possible to call code from c++ win32 dll's. But what with wp7? I wouldn't like to rewrite everything to C#.

Or maybe all this crossplatform game isn't good idea. Are there some critical pitfalls? Maybe it's better to have Obj-C only for iOS, Java only for Android, and C# only with it's silverlight and xna, and to maintain all this zoo separatelly?

Experienced mobile devs please share your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that on Android, C++ is not fully supported. It's more about pure C.

Programming in C on android is basically reserved for games. If you don't want to make your UI in OpenGL, forget it and just write it in Java. You'll need a small Java wrapper anyway.

The same applies for iOS - if you use only OpenGL, you can write everything in C and use obj-c only as a small application wrapper.

From that you can see this is reserved mainly for games. There are tools available (e.g. http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/) which can help you develop openGL games easily)

The main differences between the platforms arise from the different UI frameworks. There are tools that try to help you overcome the differences - most of them are based on HTML 5 and they are using CSS to simulate the native UI. Usually you have to sacrifice a lot of user experience.

You have to understand that if you want your application to look perfect on different platforms, you have to write the UI separately and natively for each platform. Even UI design must be different. iPhone and iPad need lots of cool animations, they must be perfect for portrait & landscape mode (including the rotating animation), using navigation bar, toolbar, split view... Android users expect something else - a different (menu) toolbar, you need to port it to a lot of different screen resolutions and the user experience will be different.

I would recommend to start with native iOS and if the app is profitable (if this is the reason for your app), develop it for other platforms. iOS app always generate most money.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone 7 has no support for native code, yet. Have a look at this question for more info: [Is it possible to program for Windows Phone 7 in standard C++ only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4539876/1205715)

If you want to code for those 3 platforms and reuse a lot of what you write, you could code in C# and use [Mono from Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com) to run your code on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). It claims to be cross platform, although I'm sure it brings the features down to a common denominator.

Answer (score -1):

I have quite good experience developing apps for iOS and Android with [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/). The code is written in JavaScript and mapped to native calls, so you get a native look and feel.

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) has a different approach. The App is written in HTML, CSS and Javascript. The advantage is that it supports more different plattforms. Including iOS, Android and Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score -1):

Among the current existing platforms , most of them support the HTML5, javascript including the iOS, Android and WP7 or upcoming WP8 also may support.

So it is advicable to write the applications using the HTML5 and javascript.

The same JavaScript HTML5 applications can be deployed on the individual platforms by using the framework which provides libraries for multiple platforms such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Morever PhoneGap is open source mobile framework free to use.

Also you can refer the following link for the [Top five HTML5 frameworks for Mobile developement.](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2011/12/02/html5-frameworks-mobile-development/)

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at MonoTouch and Mono for Android from Xamarin? http://xamarin.com/

They say you can re-use up to 90% of your app logic and create device-native user experiences / UI with access to all the native platforms API and device sensors.

Comment: I did. But I'm not sure about the performance in compare to the true native app. What about performance and memory? I'm sure that for business apps it'll be good, but for games, or other graphics and heavy calculations apps, I'm not sure.