# How to use native c code into windows phone runtime library?

Tags: c, windows-phone-8

How to use native C code into Windows Phone runtime library?

I tried several ways to do it but didn't find any help or sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This probably answers you : [Is it possible to program for Windows Phone 7 in standard C++ only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539876/is-it-possible-to-program-for-windows-phone-7-in-standard-c-only)

Not possible with WP7 but possible with WP8 for some developments

Comment: How do I include and compile "C" files in Windows Phone Runtime Component VC++ template project?