# Is it possible window phone app create in Visual C++ using vs 2012 ultimate?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

shown in image and let me know which option to create window phone app visual c++

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. There is no adequate option to create regular Windows Phone app only in c++. If you'll create Direct3D app with XAML - all interface will be in c# with Direct 3D view in Direct 3D with c++. If you'll create Direct 3D native only - you'll need to create all interface by hands. There are a lot documentation pages.
[Native code on Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), 
[C++ support from Windows Phone 8](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/C++_support_from_Windows_Phone_8), 
And right here, at SO -> [Is it possible to program for Windows Phone 7 in standard C++ only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539876/is-it-possible-to-program-for-windows-phone-7-in-standard-c-only) (with answer about Windows Phone 8)

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure C++ template for Windows Phone, only project templates for game development are supported. This is due to the XAML architecture differences between Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. While the former uses WinRT controls for XAML thus enabling projections for C++, Windows Phone 8 XAML is still the Silverlight runtime which is not projected into C++ and is based on CLR.