# Need some clarification on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, enterprise

I'm new to Windows Phone 7, please help me in getting clarification on following.

1. Like with iPhone & android, Is it possible to have our enterprise app store for Windows Phone 7? So that we can use our own app to download\install other apps or uninstall other apps.
2. Is there any built-in MDM service available with Windows Phone 7?
3. I developed sample apps in C#, but wondering whether it is possible to develop apps in C++?

Comment: I searched on internet about built-in MDM service, but no luck. If anyone can share some information, that would be big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Mango ( the next release of Windows Phone 7) will allow private marketplace. Here is [a link](http://www.geek.com/articles/windows-mobile/windows-phone-7-mango-bringing-betas-and-private-apps-to-marketplace-20110415/) about the announcement. I have not seen additional details though.
2. [System Center Configuration Manager 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/configuration-manager/cm-vnext-beta.aspx), which is available as a beta 2 will support Windows Phones.
3. No, there is no "native" SDK for Windows Phone .

Answer (score 1):

1. No. You can link to the app store but you dont have access to install things directly in WP7
2. Not to my knowledge. Perhaps another user can shed more light on this one.
3. Kind of but I would recommend using c# since its simpler and more stable. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455372/windows-phone-7-and-c-cli)

Comment: If you use unmanaged code, it will most likely not pass certification (even if it works). The native SDK can only be accessed by specific partners (e.g. carriers) and OEMs.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Part of the point of the app store is impartial vetting of apps for malicious or unscrupulous code. C++ apps for Win7 are technically possible. They are not likely to be accepted unless they are pure managed code (unless you work for the phone vendor).

In any case this is an inadvisable approach because there is a certain amount of variation in hardware between Windows 7 phones and this will rapidly become a major headache as soon as you leave the sheltered confines of managed code.