# Porting C/C++ game logic to Windows Phone 7 - how?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c++-cli, porting

I have mobile phone game cores - by this I mean the pure game logic - (framework independent, i.e. gfx rendering, data loading, user input, sound/music playing is separated), written either in C or C++ language – the code was running in the past on the Symbian, Windows Mobile 5.x 6.x and Maemo (now MeeGo) . I was thinking of porting some of those games to Windows Phone 7 using the XNA. My question is – do I need to rewrite the core in C# or I can compile to MSIL and use as a DLLs?

**Added later:**

Check this:
[Windows Phone 7 and native C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455372/windows-phone-7-and-c-cli)

Comment: Your question is probably going to be closed as NARQ, as this is almost unanswerable.

Comment: Why it is unanswerable??? I am asking if I can compile C/C++ engine code to MSIL code (similar to byte code on Java), separate them into DLL and embed into WP7 XNA application or if i have to rewrite the whole code in C#... What is strange about that? I think many developers faced the same issue...

Comment: It is unanswerable because *how are we to know if some unknown code, which may be in C or may be in some unknown version of C++ with who knows what dependencies is compilable to MSIL?*  The only real answer is "If it is, go out and buy a crapton of lottery tickets because you're the luckiest summabeach in the whole universe."

Comment: Hi, sure you cannot know all the details, but please consider my question in more general way - I have pure C and also C++ game logic already programmed, so my question is what is the best way to use it on WP7. One answer might be - there are options to compile to MSIL which you can try or I have tried it and it is better to rewrite it to C#, etc. The reason I am asking is that we are approaching the iPhone and Android - and on both platforms it looks I can use the code 'as is' - on iPhone I have no problems with compilation and on Android we plan to try NDK...

Comment: I have also mentioned that the code is framework independent, the C++ uses only <vector>, <string> and <memory>, so there is some dependency in STL - but I can easily go without them. As I have written - it was done from the beginning with keeping in mind the logic should be independent. In fact it was tested on non-mobile platform before using on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no C/C++ compiler for Phone 7. There isn't one for any version of the Compact Framework, in fact, and any "workaround" is likely to generate IL opcodes that are unsupported by the CF.

What this mean, in practicality, is that C/C++ is unusable for anyone working on Phone 7 (except the phone OEMs themselves) and your code will have to be ported to C#.

Comment: Hi ctacke - I am pretty new to WP7 platform, but I was attending the Rob Miles presentation in which he mentions that it is possibe to compile C or C++ game logic to MSIL. Was he wrong? Please see the "http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/Rob%20Miles%20Windows%20Phone%20Blue%20Book.pdf" On page 13 he writes: "_...This means that you could write some of the library code in your application in another language, for example Visual Basic, C++ or F#. It also means that if you have libraries already written in these languages you can use them in phone applications..._"

Comment: So is it possible to combine C# XNA game with C++ logic separated to DLL or not. I am anyway going to try this, but I wanted to know first if anybody is experienced with that...

Comment: No, it's not (well not with anything I'd call maintainability or supportability).  There is no C++ compiler for Phone or the CF.  Supported languages are VB.NET, C# and F#.

Answer (score 1):

Port the *games* to XNA. Don't port the *game engine* to .NET, since Windows Phone already have a *game engine* called XNA.

Comment: Hi, by saying game engine I meant the game logic (math, computation, enemy AI) - simply something I was expecting will be possible to reuse... but seems that there is no porting possibility, so  I have to rewrite it.

Comment: Do not port your Math library, use XNA Math.

Comment: Depends - if I will be able to port game logic I will keep it as is, if not possible i will surely use the XNA Math. But my games are not rocket science form mapt/physics perspective... Anyway it seems that math is pretty slow in XNA:(( Will SIMD (Mango B2) help with this?