# C++ programming in Visual Studio 2010 and Windows Mobile 7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I am trying to develop a c++ program using Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Mobile 7.5.
My questions are as follows:

1. Will a C++ program run on Windows Mobile 7.5?
2. I cant see a smart device project under Visual C++ section in Visual Studio 2010.  Is there any other way to develop a C++ program in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows phones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 and C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455372/windows-phone-7-and-c-cli)

Answer (score 2):

No, It's not possible. The Windows Phone SDK is C# only.

Comment: then what is the way to port to C++ applications of windows mobile 6.5 to windows mobile 7

Comment: I can only assume that you'll have to rewrite the application in C# and .NET since there is no backwards compatibility with 6.5.

Answer (score 2):

Windows RT and Windows 8 is having support for Native languages like C/C++. Microsoft is not successfull in killing C/C++ with windows 7 . C/C++ cant be killed as long as Operating Systems are written using C/C++

Answer (score 1):

C++ Programs can only run under Windows CE 3.0 to Windows Mobile 6.5. VC 2008 was the last Visual Studio to delvelop for that platform.

Windows Mobile 7 and later can only be developed under ALL .Net languages (not only c#). ;)

What a pity! :)

Comment: "under ALL .Net languages" So can he use C++CLI ?

Comment: No, C++/CLI is the blending of native C++ and this ***beep***ish .NET interfaces...

You're right, he can't use C++/CLI (like i said). No C++... ;)

Answer (score 0):

.net Compact Framework does not support C++.

Comment: i dont think windows 7 will survive without C++