# I have known from various sources that I can not import .dll file in Windows Phone 7 project. So what are the other ways to achieve my objective

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a live Windows Phone app.I have to encrypt my data to post it on server through a third party .dll file which was written in C++.

I have known from various sources that I can not import .dll file in Windows Phone 7 project.
So what are the other ways to achieve my objective.
Moreover,how it wolud be helpful for me if I have the source code of that .dll file.

great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can reference dll files, but not of every type. It has to be a class library made for Windows Phone or a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) (this one can be used by different platforms).

Indeed, having the source code would be helpful, you could implement the encryption and make an own class library.

**Edit:**

Andy Dent described a theoretical way to use C++ library in Windows Phone projects [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826839/350749). It is possible but not very comfortable as most of the C++ code will throw an exception: `Operation could destabilize the runtime`.

Another way would be to rewrite the code in C#, but that would mean to write nearly everything of the logic again.

Note: If you would write an application for Windows Phone 8 you could use C++ references without that problems. Have a look at [this article](http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2012/11/03/how-to-get-c-winrt-in-a-windows-phone-8-application/).

Comment: But thts the problem I am talking about,If I make a class library for windows phone,the code of .dll file itself suppose to write in c#,but the sorce code of  .dll file in my case is written in c++.So I am asking how can I import .dll of C++ in my windows phone project.
Even for a better understanding,lets suppose I have a .cpp file.I have created a .dll file of this .cpp file.Now I want to import this .dll file in my windows phone project,help me?@MatthiasG

Comment: I know it's not the exact answer to the question but upvoted just for pointing at the Portable Class Library. It's something that will be handy when I develop my app for WP8, Store and desktop!